# How to perform sorting a list hashmap?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have the following Lists:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<String,  Map<Integer, Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();
```

after doing some calculations in my map list by using the following code

```
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
    .reversed()).limit(1000).forEach(System.out::println);
```

It returns a list that is sorted based on the integer and also the name:

```
team1=1511
team4=1106
team2=805
team3=792
```

this means team1 has first place with time 1211 and team4 second place with time 1106 and so on.

Now, in my map2 I would like to be able to have the same list according to the time of the drivers, but it should sorted like this:

```
team1=1511
team4=1106
team1=1010
team2=905
team2=892
team3=750
team3=740
team4=600
```

this means that team1 has first place with time 1511 then team4 with time 1106 then again team1 with time 1010 and so on.

(basically, you have a team and each team has at least 2 drivers and after doing some calculations you want to be able to see who won the race)

for map2 i use the following to sort and to return :

```
 map2.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>comparingByKey()
    .reversed()).limit(1000).forEach(System.out::println);
```

but this doesn't return the correct result.

I want to know if its possible to do this with a hashmap, or maybe even using ArrayList??

Comment: What you need to do to calculate time of the team in map2?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I have done the calculation in a different method I just want to sort it out in a way that I explained above.

Comment: `new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();` ist a not the same data structure as `new HashMap<String, Integer>();`... This is why I do not know where you put those times ;)

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz map2 is  a list and the string is the team name and the other list that contains 2 int is the basically the list of the drivers for that team, this is being field in a diffrent method

Comment: A map is not a list, use the word map if you mean map, not list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach... why not a separate class?

```
public class Standing implements Comparable<Standing> {

    private String team;
    private Integer time;

    public Standing(String team, Integer time) {
        this.team = team;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTeam() {
        return this.team;
    }

    public Integer getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.team + "=" + this.time;
    }

    public int compareTo(Standing standing) {
        return (this.time).compareTo(standing.getTime());
    }
}
```

Here I would use:

```
Map<String,  ArrayList<Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>();
```

this way:

```
TreeSet<Standing> standingSet = new TreeSet<Standing>();
for (String team : map2.keySet()) {
    standingSet.add(new Standing(team, map2.get(team).get(0)));
    standingSet.add(new Standing(team, map2.get(team).get(1)));
}

for (Standing standing : standingSet) {
    System.out.println(standing);
}
```

Comment: it doest work, I get error for Map<String,  Map<Integer, Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer, Integer>>();

Comment: It should be `Map<String, ArrayList<Integer, Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer, Integer>>();` instead.

Comment: not really again this error: Multiple markers at this line
 - Incorrect number of arguments for type ArrayList<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer, 
  Integer>
 - Incorrect number of arguments for type ArrayList<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer, 
  Integer>

Comment: Try `Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();`

Comment: doent completely work but I got some idea after seeing your solution.

Comment: at least some idea ;)

Comment: Actually I was able to make your code work, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `map2` contains:

```
team1: {
    1: 1506,
    2: 1010
},
team4: {
    1: 1106,
    2: 600
}
```

... then you can get it sorted by doing:

```
List<DriverResult> results = map2.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
        .map(e2 -> new DriverResult(e.getKey(), e2.getKey(), e2.getValue()))
    )
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(DriverResult::getTime))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And this helper class:

```
public class DriverResult {
  private String team;
  private int number;
  private int time;

  public DriverResult(String team, int number, int time) {
    this.team = team;
    this.time = time;
    this.number = number;
  }

  public int getTime() {
    return time;
  }
}
```